# How to download japanese history stock prices automatically from google finance in python

Tags: python, finance, stock

I use python to analyze Japanese stock prices. I want to get Japanese historical stock prices to get from google finance.  I also refer to googlefinance0.7 ( https://pypi.python.org/pypi/googlefinance ) and pandas, but they are not support Japanese stock prices. So how to download japanese history stock prices automatically from google finance? Or are there references to program code in python?

Comment: If you can find a webpage that has the stocks that you are looking for, using `requests` and `beautifulsoup` you can get the stocks you want.

Answer (score 1):

[Quandl](https://www.quandl.com/data/TSE) has all the historical data sets you need.

It's designed for easy usage with Python so for [Tokyo Stock Exchange TOPIX Index](https://www.quandl.com/data/TSE/TOPIX-Tokyo-Stock-Exchange-TOPIX-Index) :

```
import quandl
mydata = quandl.get("TSE/TOPIX")
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. quandl is so useful to use. One of quandl demerit is too short date stock prices to get. Are there any longer data stock prices to get?

Comment: here is a sample code proving longer date stock prices: https://hk29.hatenablog.jp/entry/2020/04/25/170130